# How to set presto.s3.xxx properties when running flink from an IDE?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm able to successfully run my flink job which saves to S3 using `./bin/flink run ...`.

For this to work, I had to copy the flink-s3-fs-presto jar to my `$FLINK_HOME/lib` folder and I also had to configure my S3 connection details in my `flink-conf.yaml`:

> You need to configure both s3.access-key and s3.secret-key in Flink’s
>   flink-conf.yaml:
>
> ```
> s3.access-key: your-access-key
> s3.secret-key: your-secret-key
> ```
>
> Source: [flink aws docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/aws.html#access-keys-discouraged)

I also had to set a property `s3.endpoint` because I'm using S3 from IBM Cloud.

This all works fine when I run using `./bin/flink run`.

However, when I try to run my job from my IDE (IntelliJ), I get the following error:

> org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Cannot initialize task 'DataSink (TextOutputFormat (s3://xxxx/folder) - UTF-8)': Unable to load credentials from service endpoint

I've set an environment variable in the IDE run job, `FLINK_CONF_DIR` to point to my flink-conf.yaml and I can see that my configuration properties are picked up:

```
11:04:39,487 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration - Loading configuration property: s3.access-key, ****
11:04:39,487 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration - Loading configuration property: s3.secret-key, ****
11:04:39,487 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration - Loading configuration property: s3.endpoint, s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net
```

However, I'm getting an error that suggests these properties are not getting passed to the presto library when I run from my IDE:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.fs.s3presto.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint
```

Also, to validate this theory, if I step through the code when running from the IDE, I can see that my endpoint property is not applied:

[image]

... and drilling into the Hadoop configuration, I can see that the flink configuration is an empty map:

[image]

Digging a bit deeper, I can see that the `org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem#getUnguardedFileSystem()` is creating a new empty Configuration:

```
        // this "default" initialization makes sure that the FileSystem class works
        // even when not configured with an explicit Flink configuration, like on
        // JobManager or TaskManager setup
        if (FS_FACTORIES.isEmpty()) {
            initialize(new Configuration());
        }
```

How can I configure the `s3.access-key`, `s3.secret-key` and `s3.endpoint` properties when running from an IDE?

Answer (score 5):

Simply call

```
FileSystem.initialize(GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration(System.getenv("FLINK_CONF_DIR")));
```

before

```
env.execute()
```

will solve the issue.

Remember you still have to put your secret key and access key in flink-conf.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

create core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
        <value>xxxx</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
        <value>xxxxx</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

and add

```
    Map par = new HashMap();par.put("fs.hdfs.hadoopconf", "path to core-site.xml";
    ParameterTool pt = ParameterTool.fromMap(par);
    env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(pt);
```